# Javascript detect variable change after # in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Example:

```
http://localhost/#view=1
```

If I want to get that variable "view", I need to get `window.location.href`, and then split the `#` and do something more.

This is my question:

```
<a href="#view=1">View 1</a>
<a href="#view=2">View 2</a>
```

Is there anyway to detect when View 1 click or view 2 click? For people click on View 2, a function will do for `view=2`.

OR I must do something like this:

```
<a href="#view=1" onclick="setview(1);">View 1</a>
<a href="#view=2" onclick="setview(2);">View 2</a>
```

I want when people copy the link `http://localhost/#view=2` and send to there friend, the function `setview(2)` will be run when their friend visit the URL,  and they don't need to click the link.

Comment: `window.location.hash` can give you that directly. You shouldn't have to split your URL.

Comment: You want the `onHashChange` event.

Comment: Is there anyway to know onhashchange without use other plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can use `hashChange` event

```
$(function(){
  // Bind the event.
  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    // Alerts every time the hash changes!
    alert( location.hash );
  })

  // Trigger the event (useful on page load).
  $(window).hashchange();
});
```

And now in the `$(window).hashchange();` function, put your code:

```
$(window).hashchange(function(){
  $(location.hash).show();
});
```

In your case, it would be:

```
$(window).hashchange(function(){
  setview(location.hash[strlen(location.hash)-1]); // Get the last character, if this doesn't work.
});
```

Forgot to add the plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/, which you would need to use.

Comment: there is no shortcut `.hashchange()` method in jQuery API...need to use `on()`

Comment: I gave the definition for using `hashchange` with jQuery. It is here: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: OK...but that is using a plugin that was not referenced in your solution. Can simply use `on()` for what you are providing without a plugin

Comment: @Ken: `$(window).on('hashchange', function(){ /* do stuff */ });` Also: check out the [API reference for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).